# Publicar WCF service no IIS com ambiente de teste

Tags: web-service, vb.net, iis, wcf

Criei um webservice utilizando WCF .NET 4.0, e hospedei no IIS do nosso servidor local (quando tudo estiver ok será migrado para um servidor na web). Na aplicação winform consegui consumir o método sem problemas, porém estou tentando criar um ambiente teste, com uma url diferente, e não consegui configurar o web.config/app.config corretamente para isso. Tentei utilizando baseAddress e dois EndPoints distintos.

Segue abaixo a configuração utilizada:
(web.config - WCF ServiceHost)

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceComunicacao" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="WsComunicacao.ServiceComunicacao">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.0.101/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="ws_teste/ServiceComunicacao.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceComunicacao"
        contract="WsComunicacao.IServiceComunicacao" name="EndPoint_IServiceComunicacao_Teste" />

    <endpoint address="ws/ServiceComunicacao.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceComunicacao"
        contract="WsComunicacao.IServiceComunicacao" name="EndPoint_IServiceComunicacao" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

(app.config - WinForm Client App)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceComunicacao" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>        
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://192.168.0.101/ws_teste/ServiceComunicacao.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceComunicacao"
          contract="WsComunicacao.IServiceComunicacao" name="EndPoint_IServiceComunicacao_Teste" />

      <endpoint address="http://192.168.0.101/ws/ServiceComunicacao.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceComunicacao"
          contract="WsComunicacao.IServiceComunicacao" name="EndPoint_IServiceComunicacao" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

E o código utlizado para consumir o webservice:

```
Dim wsClient As WsComunicacao.ServiceComunicacaoClient
If Debugger.IsAttached Then
    wsClient = New WsComunicacao.ServiceComunicacaoClient("EndPoint_IServiceComunicacao_Teste")
Else
    wsClient = New WsComunicacao.ServiceComunicacaoClient("EndPoint_IServiceComunicacao")
End If

Dim resp As WsComunicacao.Resposta = wsClient.EnviarDados(dados)
```

Ao chamar o método EnviarDados, ocorre o erro:

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.0.101/ws_teste/ServiceComunicacao.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

Comment: Jota, no navegador, o endereço http://192.168.0.101/ws_teste/ServiceComunicacao.svc responde normalmente?

Comment: Você deseja duas URLs para acessar o mesmo serviço WCF? Você já tentou usando o mesmo name de endpoint? Invés de um endpoint com EndPoint_IServiceComunicacao_Teste e outro com o name EndPoint_IServiceComunicacao, teste com o mesmo nome.

Comment: Vitor, os dois endereços estão respondendo corretamente pelo browser.

Comment: Oi Renan, no caso se eu colocar o mesmo nome, como eu poderia direcionar qual eu quero via código?. Pra ser sincero, é a primeira vez que mexo com WCF, não entendi muito bem a função desses EndPoint's. Se alguém tiver outra idéia de como implementar um ambiente de teste, estou aberto a sugestões, pode até ser em servidores separados tipo o de teste ser na rede local e o de produção na web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou responder a pergunta caso alguém esteja na mesma situação.
Após pesquisar bastante resolvi efetuar a configuração via código ao invés de usar o .ini, o framework fornece propriedades para configurar todos os parâmetros disponíveis no .ini, ficando assim, bem mais fácil de customizar.

Isso também resolveu um outro grande problema, no meu caso minha rotina estava em uma Dll que era refenciada em outros executáveis, então eu teria que configurar o app.config em cada um desses executáveis.

Segue o código utilizado:

```
Private Function ObterConexaoWebservice() As WsComunicacao.IServiceComunicacaoChannel
    Try
        If _wsComunicacao Is Nothing Then
            Dim b As New WSHttpBinding
            b.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647
            b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
            b.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647
            b.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None
            b.SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)

            'Dim edp As New EndpointAddress("http://192.168.0.101/ws_teste/ServiceComunicacao.svc")
            'Dim edp As New EndpointAddress("http://localhost:2392/WcfServiceHost/ServiceComunicacao.svc")
            Dim edp As New EndpointAddress(DadosConfigGerais.ConfigSistema.url_wscomunicacao)
            Dim fab As New ChannelFactory(Of WsComunicacao.IServiceComunicacaoChannel)(b, edp)
            _wsComunicacao = fab.CreateChannel
            _wsComunicacao.Open()
        End If

        Return _wsComunicacao
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Function
```